# drag user controls in metro application for windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I am developing an metro application (Windows 8) in c#, that allows; to drag the controls/elements (Button, text Boxes etc), and i am not sure how to do drag in metro app.
Please guide me, 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would MouseDragElementBehavior satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete source code. You can drag and drop any control onto canvas. Right now I am giving you example of button and textbox. For all other control the process is same.

XAML code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridView 
        x:Name="GridViewControl" 
        AllowDrop="True" 
        Background="#FF2E5073" 
        CanDragItems="True" 
        DragItemsStarting="GridViewControl_DragItemsStarting"
        SelectionMode="None" 
        >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock 
                        FontSize="14" 
                        Text="{Binding}" 
                        />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel 
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
    <Canvas x:Name="Form" 
            AllowDrop="True" 
            Background="Black" 
            Drop="Form_Drop" 
            Grid.Column="1"
            />
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var ObserControl = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Textbox", "Button" };
        GridViewControl.ItemsSource = ObserControl;
    }

    private void Form_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        object sourceItem;
        e.Data.Properties.TryGetValue("Item", out sourceItem);
        double XPos = e.GetPosition(GridViewControl).X - 160;
        double YPos = e.GetPosition(GridViewControl).Y;
        if (sourceItem.ToString() == "Textbox")
        {
            var newTextbox = new TextBox();
            newTextbox.Text = "Textbox";
            newTextbox.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, XPos);
            newTextbox.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, YPos);
            Form.Children.Add(newTextbox);
        }
        if (sourceItem.ToString() == "Button")
        {
            var newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Content = "Button";
            newButton.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, XPos);
            newButton.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, YPos);
            Form.Children.Add(newButton);
        }
    }

    private void GridViewControl_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Items.FirstOrDefault();
        e.Data.Properties.Add("Item", item);
    }
}
```